# train_test_slplit() function behavior

Tags: data-mining, train-test-split

How can the values in `X` become this in X_train after `train_test_split()` function? How can I avoid that?

[image]

Comment: You can rename your variables then pass it back into the test train split function  X1 = X and y1 = y then use those variable names in the_test train_split()

Comment: which variables do you actually want to split? I think you want to run train_test_split() on the X at the top rather than the X, that you have assigned from the dataframe?